# How to hide action bar button in fragment when Navigation Drawer is open

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I use Navigation Drawer and for one of the fragments I have different menu. For that fragment when navigation drawer is open, how to hide the action bar's button?
For example on the picture ( http://prntscr.com/7ur712 ) it is button REFRESH.

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
**setHasOptionsMenu(true);** }

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
**inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);**
}
```

Comment: when you create the optionsmenu you can keep a variable of the menu item that you want to hide. then you have to hide it inside the drawer callback for draw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to update your actionBar buttons is to call the `invalidateOptionsMenu()` when your `NavigationDrawer` is opened/closed.

According to the Android training documentation page, when you create your `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, you should override the `onDrawerClosed` and the `onDrawerOpened` methods:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) { 

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */ 
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            } 

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */ 
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            } 
        };
```

Also, in your `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method, you can detect if your drawer is open or not, and load the menu corresponding to your drawer state:

```
/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */ 
    @Override 
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view 
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

For more information, you can see the Android developper documentation here : https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html
(cf section: Listen for Open and Close Events)

Comment: This works for fragment. When I close navigation drawer REFRESH button is gone. But when I click on Navigation Drawer and open another fragment,  application crashes..

MESSAGE:


FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at ---.onPrepareOptionsMenu(---.java:218)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performPrepareOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:1885)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:2032)

Comment: Are you sure that your menu contains all the items you try to access ? Do you know which object or method call cause this NPE ? Also, instead of calling the invalidateOptionMenu() method, you can call the supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() if you use the support library

Comment: I solved it..
I put if the_refresh_button != null do the code. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Implement the **[ActionBarDrawerToogle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html)** to get the state of the navigation drawer. Call `invalidateOptionsMenu();` to invalidate the menu on open/close state of the navigation drawer.

Later based on the state you can show/hide navigation items using:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // inflate menu from xml
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);

    if (mState == MENU_HIDDEN)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++)
            menu.getItem(i).setVisible(false);
    }
}
```